# Post Status Frontend Announcement

Tags: posts, post-status, notifications

I want to announce the logged-in user in front end (theme, not the backend), how many posts he has with htis statuses:

1. awaiting moderation
2. approved (published)
3. not approved(rejected)

since last announcement. Are there any plugins for this? Are there any good keywords to search for such a thing?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an easy to use function to do that for you.

Like so:

```
<?php
function sg_user_posts_by_type($userid, $post_status) {
    $args = array(
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'post_status'   => array($post_status),
        'author'        => $userid
    );
    $count_posts = count(get_posts($args)); 
    return $count_posts;
}


if (is_user_logged_in()) {

    // GET CURRENT USER DATA
    $user_id            = get_current_user_id();
    $user_data          = get_userdata($user_id);

    $publish_count      = sg_user_posts_by_type($user_id, 'publish');
    $pending_count      = sg_user_posts_by_type($user_id, 'pending');
    $draft_count        = sg_user_posts_by_type($user_id, 'draft');


    echo '
        <h3>Hey '.$user_data->last_name.', You got:</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>'.$publish_count.' published Posts</li>
            <li>'.$pending_count.' pending Posts</li>
            <li>'.$draft_count.' drafts</li>
        </ul>
    ';
}
?>
```

you could make it less resource costly if you need to but this should work fine.
Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thanks for your reponse. what do you mean by `you could make it last resource costly if you need to`. my english sucks.

Comment: i mean you could use wp_query instead of get_posts and ask for IDS only in the query to make it return exactly what you need and not the entire post objects.